# CSS Media query not working for some reason

Tags: css, media-queries, media

I need to make a website responsive built in 2012. I'm editing the style.css file (Wordpress website) but the media query doesn't work for some reason. Already checked the css file online, and the media query is in it.

The website I'm talking about is [www.carter-realestate.be](http://www.carter-realestate.be)
There is nothing wrong with the media query, I've done this a hundred times before.
The style.css file with the media query is online, so you can check it out.

Anybody knows an explanation for this?

Comment: Could you post some code with this?

Comment: @Gab you have an entire website full of code. Problem is already solved.

Comment: Well, since the problem is already solved and seems to have been fixed on the web site, this question become less relevant for other users who would get the same problem. By simply posting a code snippet, the question will still make sense when the original website's code get fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a space between "and" and "("

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
```

Comment: How can I have overseen that. Thanks a lot. *embarrassed*

Answer (score 1):

Trying changing it to:

```
@media only screen and(max-width: 900px){
    body{
        background-color: red !important;
        color: blue;
    }

    h1{
        font-size: 15em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some of the styles were changing in my media query and some weren't.  Adding the !important fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

There's some script on your page that's re-writing the `@media` rules.

Looking at your source code in `style.csss` I see:

```
@media all and(max-width: 900px){
body{
    background-color: red !important;
    color: blue;
}

h1{
    font-size: 15em;
}
}
```

But checking it out in Firebug (via Firefox) I see the code changed in the DOM to:

```
@media not all {
    body {
        background-color: #FF0000 !important;
       color: #0000FF;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 15em;
    }
}
```

Somewhere a script is re-writing the `@media` rules to **"not all"**.

Try disabling all scripts in the WordPress plugin and refresh the page. If that doesn't work, edit the HTML and comment out any remaining scripts loading. Then add a script or plugin back in one by one until you find which is re-writing the DOM.